# Trying to remotely access my machine after SSH port has been closed

Tags: ssh, port

I was trying to run a license server on my Ubuntu machine, through port `27020`. I was using my server remotely, through an `ssh` connection, since I'm currently abroad. For one reason or another I did not manage to get the software which requires this license to work, and I started to check if for some reason this port was not accessible. Through Google searches I ended up reading about the `ufw` firewall, and that it might be blocking the port. So I ran:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 27020
```

As it turns out, the `ufw` service was not enabled beforehand, since Ubuntu defaults to that. All the other ports that were being listened to before, including `ssh`'s `22`, became blocked by the server after I rebooted. Now I can't `ssh` into this machine anymore and as far as I can tell I need physical access to it so that I can fix it. I know what you're thinking about me and I deserve all of it. The thing is, it looks like my machine may now be listening to port `27020`. Is there any way that I can gain control by exploiting this, or am I deservingly screwed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid you’re screwed. It’s unlikely that the licence server has a vulnerability that you can exploit to gain access or reboot the machine. Note that you don’t *necessarily* need physical access, if your server is set up to allow out-of-band access through a console server or a virtual console, but that depends on your exact hardware setup.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have any management capabilities at the hardware level. I'll have to ask someone to go over and type a few commands for me. I guess I learned a lesson here...